# Replacing and restructuring list elements in place

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I have 200k pieces of data like this (only two elements shown), imported from a CSV file

```
{{2015, 11, 12, "17:04", 1.0811}, {2015, 11, 12, "17:05", 1.0811}}
```

and want to turn it into a list suitable for `DateListPlot` (I will only take small chunks once I have a plottable list], i.e. like

```
{{{2015, 11, 12, 17,04}, 1.0811}, {{2015, 11, 12, 17:05}, 1.0811}}
```

**EDIT** The first two lines of the CSV file are, verbatim,

```
Date_Time,Day,Month,Year,Date,Time,Open,Close,High,Low
12/11/2015 17:04,12,11,2015,12/11/2015,17:04,1.08110,1.08109,1.08110,1.08109
```

**END EDIT**

Having looked at `Replace`, and general List manipulation instructions I realise I don't know where to begin as I am still new to Mathematica. I have looked at related questions but none has seemed appropriate since I wish to replace and restructure at the same time.

I suppose I could simply build a new table and use `DateValue` to get the Hour and Minute from Part 4 of each sub list, but this seems heavy handed and I would also like to take the opportunity to learn more elegant/efficient methods of performing such list manipulations.

What would you recommend - and why?

[And - is there a way of forcing a list structure during the import so that the CVS fields for dates/time values are automatically combined into such a sublist?]

Comment: "is there a way of forcing a list structure" ... not sure I understand, but see second argument of SemanticImport (not Import).  Is that what you want?

Comment: Indeed, that might deliver the end result I am looking for the overall import operation, but having come across the problem of changing a list as described I would like to know that answer too. Was going AFK when your comment came in so will have to check later. Thx.

Comment: You can get your desired list if you do: `{#[[1 ;; 4]], Last[#]} & /@ list`

Comment: If you can upload a small sample of your CSV file, I can look into how to semantically import it properly.

Comment: @dan7geo I have added header and 1st line; now that my attention has been drawn to SemanticImport I could do the simple part of making one list per CSV row, it's structuring it as required for `DateListPlot` that would be most illuminating

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, you just need to use Map as @mgamer suggested? (`/@` is operator form of Map. see also `Most` and `Last`). you can also use a replacement such as this: `Replace[list, {a__, last_} :> {{a}, last}, 1]`

Comment: @mgamer @amr Almost - I get `{{2015, 11, 12, "17:04"}, 1.0811}` so the time has not been parsed correctly, but thanks

Comment: It is just a rearranging of the list, no values are changed, so what is wrong? and what do you mean with "not been parsed correctly"?

Answer (score 3):

To create a list of DateObjects and values you can first do this:

```
list = {DateObject@Join[#[[;; 3]], 
 ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#[[4]], ":"]], #[[5]]} & /@ data
```

Replace `data` with your data. ( `/@` stands for [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and `# &` notation creates a [pure](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) function)

Then you can run the following to plot your data:

```
DateListPlot@list
```

EDIT:

To create a function that processes the list:

```
makePlottable := {DateObject@Join[#[[;; 3]], 
 ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#[[4]], ":"]], #[[5]]} & /@ # &
```

(This feature might be useful for further processing: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html )

Comment: I expect that works as promised, but having said I am still new to MMA in the question I'm afraid it's too terse for me, but my attempt to grok it is: DateObject (ah! {y, m, d..} or dateobj for DateListPlot) takes  ymdhm(s) #[[;; 3]] picks Y M D, StringSplit must be getting h &m; all datetime stuff is then joined and becomes the DateObject and item 5 (the value) appended. # must be a placeholder for the current list item but how the #, & and /@ work together escapes me for now :(

Comment: Could you expand that expression as function calls so it looks like e.g. `makePlottable[aList_List] := Map[...` I tried and failed and this would help me understand & learn.

Comment: OK, I've got as far as `makePlottable[aList_List] := {DateObject[Join[#[[;; 3]]], ToExpression [StringSplit[#[[4]], ":"]]], #[[5]]} & /@ aList` but how do I replace the & /@ at the end?

Comment: See update to the answer with links explaining those things.

Comment: :) Love the extra "# &" after the "& /@" I was already unclear about :) Where might I find such non-trivial examples explained step by step (or operator by operator) so I can decode for my still rather procedural brain? I've upvoted your answer but, since I did ask for the "why?" (meaning: how it works)  I haven't accepted it (yet)

Comment: I'd suggest going through this quickly https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperationsOverview.html

Comment: Or https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/pure-functions/ , if you have more time then this book is an excellent introduction http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org